# Why can I no longer remove "General:" when using \PrintChanges as of doc 3?

Tags: package-writing, dtx, trackchanges, doc

As of version 3, the `doc` package provides `reportchangedates` option to display dates along with package changes. I want to remove the word "General" and the colon that follows it from the list of changes. Removing "General" is trivial using `\renewcommand{\generalname}{}` but the removing the colon is harder. Prior `doc 3` I had been using a hack based on this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283894/218142 and it worked fine, and still does. This hack doesn't address the `reportchangedates` option and in fact makes it superfluous. I thought I could use a similar hack by using the new `doc 3` code

```
\def\changes@#1#2#3{%
  \protected@edef\@tempa{\noexpand\glossary{#1%
                   \ifdoc@reportchangedates
                     \space -- #2\fi
                   \levelchar
                   \ifx\saved@macroname\@empty
                      \quotechar!%
                      \actualchar
                      \generalname
                   \else
                      \saved@indexname
                      \actualchar
                      \string\verb% % to fool emacs highlighting
                      \quotechar*%
                      \verbatimchar\saved@macroname
                      \verbatimchar
                   \fi
                   :\levelchar #3}}% <- I NEED TO CHANGE THIS LINE
  \@tempa\endgroup\@esphack}
```

but when I do, I get an error that `\saved@indexname` is an undefined control sequence. I have tried defining and redefining it and nothing works. I am using the `tcolorbox` `documentation` library if that matters (I have looked at its source code and haven't found anything obvious). I see in the `doc 3` source code that `\saved@indexname` is initially empty and I see where it is eventually conditionally redefined to `\expandafter\@gobble\saved@macroname` but that change doesn't seem to help because then I get an error that `\saved@macroname` is undefined, but it is ostensibly initialized to be empty and I don't see how it is being changed.

I have whittled down a MWE `.dtx` file below, which **must** be named `sample.dtx` to work properly. The old hack that works is commented out; the new attempt is the functional one. Only `.pdf` and `.sty` files (no `.ins` file) will be created.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\usedir{tex/latex/sample}
\preamble
Big Premamble
\endpreamble

\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}

\obeyspaces
\Msg{*************************************************************}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{* To finish the  installation, open a command line and      *}
\Msg{* type the following, repeating 2-4 until there are no      *}
\Msg{* warnings:                                                 *}
\Msg{*   2. lualatex sample.dtx  (lualatex is required)          *}
\Msg{*   3. makeindex -s gind.ist -o sample.ind sample.idx       *}
\Msg{*   4. makeindex -s gglo.ist -o sample.gls sample.glo       *}
\Msg{* Move the *.sty file into a directory searched by TeX.     *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{*************************************************************}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%
%<*internal>
\usedir{tex/latex/sample}
\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,nohyperref]{ltxdoc} % let tcolorbox load hyperref
%\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage[nohyperref]{doc}
\SetupDoc{reportchangedates}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\PassOptionsToPackage{listings,documentation}{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[listings,documentation]{tcolorbox}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\tcbset{%
  index german settings,%
  color hyperlink = blue,%
}%
%  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156383/218142
\newcommand*{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand*{\sample}{\textsf{sample}}

%%%%% Local Hack That Works
^^A\renewcommand{\generalname}{} % gets rid of General
^^A\makeatletter
^^A\renewcommand*{\changes@}[3]{%
^^A \protected@edef\@tempa{%
^^A  \noexpand\glossary{#1 -- #2\levelchar % formatted as in doc v3
^^A   \ifx\saved@macroname\@empty
^^A    \space\actualchar\generalname
^^A   \else
^^A    \expandafter\@gobble\saved@macroname
^^A    \actualchar
^^A    \string\verb\quotechar*\verbatimchar\saved@macroname\verbatimchar
^^A   \fi
^^A    #3}}% <-- IT'S THIS LINE I CHANGED
^^A \@tempa
^^A \endgroup
^^A \@esphack
^^A}%
^^A\makeatother
%%%%% End Local Hack That Works
%%%%% Local Hack That Doesn't Work
\renewcommand{\generalname}{} % gets rid of General
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\changes@}[3]{%
  \protected@edef\@tempa{\noexpand\glossary{#1%
                   \ifdoc@reportchangedates
                     \space -- #2\fi
                   \levelchar
                   \ifx\saved@macroname\@empty
                      \quotechar!%
                      \actualchar
                      \generalname
                   \else
                      \saved@indexname
                      \actualchar
                      \string\verb% % to fool emacs highlighting
                      \quotechar*%
                      \verbatimchar\saved@macroname
                      \verbatimchar
                   \fi
                   #3}}% <-- IT'S THIS LINE I CHANGED
  \@tempa\endgroup\@esphack}
\makeatother
%%%%% End Local Hack That Doesn't Work

\DisableCrossrefs
\PageIndex
\CodelineNumbered
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
  \newpage
  \PrintIndex
  \PrintChanges
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \IndexPrologue{\section{Index}Page numbers refer to page where the 
%   corresponding entry is documented and/or referenced.}
%
% \changes{v1.0.0}{2022-06-29}{Initial release}
% \section{Introduction}
% The \sample{} package is silly and does absolutely nothing useful.
%
% \subsection{Nothing Much}
% There's not much to say here.
%
% \subsection{The first command}
%\iffalse
%<*example>
%\fi
\begin{docCommand}{sampleversion}{}
  Typesets the current version and build date.
\end{docCommand}
\begin{dispExample*}{sidebyside = false}
  The version is \sampleversion{} and is a stable build.
\end{dispExample*}
%\iffalse
%</example>
%\fi
%
% \MaybeStop{}
%
% \section{\sample\ Source Code}
% This is the complete source code to the \sample{} package.
%
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\sample@version{1.0.0}
\def\sample@date{2022-06-29}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-02-02]
\DeclareRelease{v1.0.0}{2022-06-29}{sample.sty}
\DeclareCurrentRelease{v\sample@version}{\sample@date}
\ProvidesPackage{sample}
  [\sample@date\space v\sample@version\space A silly sample]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Define a convenient package version command.
% \changes{v1.0.0}{2022-06-29}{Added a macro.}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*{\sampleversion}{v\sample@version\space dated \sample@date}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{iftex}          % needed for requiring LuaLaTeX
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}   % needed for Unicode support
\RequireLuaTeX                  % require this engine
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
% \Finale
```

Comment: The change date which the other question asked about has been included into doc directly. Why didn't you ask for a similar option instead of transporting a hack through the years?

Comment: Yes I know the date is included with an option in doc 3 but there is no option to not typeset the colon and it is ultimately the colon I need to remove. Only one line needs to be changed but there are macros that are apparently undefined that keep the edit from working.

Comment: the undefined command is `\saved`, which mean that you messed up the catcode of `@` with your hack. And I know that there is no option. But did you ever requested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like answering my own questions, but I knew redefining `changes@` worked in a straight `.tex` file and simply removing `:` and `\levelchar` couldn't possibly change any catcodes.

Further experimenting showed the solution is to put the modified `changes@` definition inside the commented portion of the `.dtx` file, which I do not fully understand because before `doc 3` I didn't have to do this. I also had to remove the `<` character since it seemed to be causing problems too, possibly related to guard syntax. If someone can explain why this fix works I will gladly accept that answer.

Nevertheless, here is the corrected MWE.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\usedir{tex/latex/sample}
\preamble
Big Premamble
\endpreamble

\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}

\obeyspaces
\Msg{*************************************************************}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{* To finish the  installation, open a command line and      *}
\Msg{* type the following, repeating 2-4 until there are no      *}
\Msg{* warnings:                                                 *}
\Msg{*   2. lualatex sample.dtx  (lualatex is required)          *}
\Msg{*   3. makeindex -s gind.ist -o sample.ind sample.idx       *}
\Msg{*   4. makeindex -s gglo.ist -o sample.gls sample.glo       *}
\Msg{* Move the *.sty file into a directory searched by TeX.     *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{*************************************************************}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%
%<*internal>
\usedir{tex/latex/sample}
\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,nohyperref]{ltxdoc} % let tcolorbox load hyperref
%\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage[nohyperref]{doc}
\SetupDoc{reportchangedates}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\PassOptionsToPackage{listings,documentation}{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[listings,documentation]{tcolorbox}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\tcbset{%
  index german settings,%
  color hyperlink = blue,%
}%
%  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156383/218142
\newcommand*{\pkg}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand*{\sample}{\textsf{sample}}

\DisableCrossrefs
\PageIndex
\CodelineNumbered
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
  \newpage
  \PrintIndex
  \PrintChanges
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \IndexPrologue{\section{Index}Page numbers refer to page where the 
%   corresponding entry is documented and/or referenced.}
%
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand{\generalname}{}
% \renewcommand{\changes@}[3]{%
%   \protected@edef\@tempa{\noexpand\glossary{#1%
%     \ifdoc@reportchangedates%
%       \space -- #2\fi%
%     \levelchar%
%     \ifx\saved@macroname\@empty%
%       \quotechar!%
%       \actualchar%
%       \generalname%
%     \else%
%       \saved@indexname%
%       \actualchar%
%       \string\verb% % to fool emacs highlighting
%       \quotechar*%
%       \verbatimchar\saved@macroname%
%       \verbatimchar%
%     \fi%
%     #3}}%
%  \@tempa\endgroup\@esphack}%
% \makeatother
%
% \changes{v1.0.0}{2022-06-29}{Initial release}
% \section{Introduction}
% The \sample{} package is silly and does absolutely nothing useful.
%
% \subsection{Nothing Much}
% There's not much to say here.
%
% \subsection{The first command}
%\iffalse
%<*example>
%\fi
\begin{docCommand}{sampleversion}{}
  Typesets the current version and build date.
\end{docCommand}
\begin{dispExample*}{sidebyside = false}
  The version is \sampleversion{} and is a stable build.
\end{dispExample*}
%\iffalse
%</example>
%\fi
%
% \MaybeStop{}
%
% \section{\sample\ Source Code}
% This is the complete source code to the \sample{} package.
%
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\sample@version{1.0.0}
\def\sample@date{2022-06-29}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-02-02]
\DeclareRelease{v1.0.0}{2022-06-29}{sample.sty}
\DeclareCurrentRelease{v\sample@version}{\sample@date}
\ProvidesPackage{sample}
  [\sample@date\space v\sample@version\space A silly sample]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Define a convenient package version command.
% \changes{v1.0.0}{2022-06-29}{Added a macro.}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*{\sampleversion}{v\sample@version\space dated \sample@date}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{iftex}          % needed for requiring LuaLaTeX
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}   % needed for Unicode support
\RequireLuaTeX                  % require this engine
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
% \Finale
```